# gtsummary - summary table in wide format for multiple variables

Tags: variables, output, gtsummary

Is there a way to produce a summary table for `dataframe` with multiple continuous variables (wide format) within `gtsummary` package? So I want to get a table with summary statistics in raws (like in multi-line display), for each variable in the same wide format as in the `dataframe`.

I've tried to use `tbl_summary` function, but all variables in output are arranged in long format.

The final table I want to get looks like in the picture.
[Sample three variables with summary statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFoT9.png)

Comment: Can you please update your post with an example of what you'd like the results to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example how you could make this work

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

# number of decimal places to round statistics
decimals <- list(age = c(1, 2, 1), marker = c(3, 4, 3))

# vector of column names to summarize
c("age", "marker") |> 
  lapply(
    \(x) {
      trial |> 
        # rename and select variable
        select(var = all_of(x)) |> 
        tbl_summary(
          type = ~"continuous2",
          statistic = ~c("{mean} ({sd})", "{median}"),
          digits = ~decimals[[x]],
          label = ~"generic_label",
          missing = "no"
        ) |> 
        # update header to indcate the variable
        modify_header(stat_0 = glue::glue("**{x}**")) |> 
        # remove the header row
        remove_row_type(type = "header") |> 
        # remove the default indentation
        modify_table_styling(columns = label, text_format = "indent", undo_text_format = TRUE)
    }
  ) |> 
  tbl_merge(tab_spanner = FALSE) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **age** | **marker** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean (SD) | 47.2 (14.31) | 0.916 (0.8593) |
| Median | 47.0 | 0.639 |

<sup>Created on 2023-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello Daniel, the code you provided works fine for my dataset, so I got what expected. Thank you for that, it`s very useful. Because I`m mostly working with pharmacokinetic data sometimes I need more statistics do display than listed as pre-defined arguments according to the package manual. Say, I often need geometric mean and CV to be displayed along with other common statistics (mean, sd, median etc). Is there any posibility to do this within gtsummary functions?

Comment: For continuous summaries, there are no special internal functions. When you specify `"{mean} ({sd})"`, it's running the `mean()` and `sd()` functions. You can use _any_ function that you define or a function from a loaded package, e.g. `c("{romans_custom_function}", "{mean}", "{sd}")`, where `romans_custom_function <- function(x) sd(x) / mean(x) * 100`

Comment: Hi Daniel, it works fine! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Daniel, sorry for so many questions, but I'm trying to find out flexibility of gtsummary package for my needs.. How I can specify number of decimals for any specific variable anf for any statistics? E.g. I want that a mean of variable A to be displayed with 2 digits and a mean of variable B to be displayed with 3 decimals. The same is for SD, CV etc. I know the solution which can be applied accross all variables, but how about specific combinations I have no idea (say, mean A: 3 digits and SD A: 4 digits; mean B: 1 digits, SD B: 2 digits). Appreciate your help.

Comment: i updated the example to show how to specify the decimals for rounding

Comment: Hi Daniel, it's very flexible, thanks. If you don't mind I'll ask you in case of questions concerning gtsummary :)